# query to get multiple rows with or without group concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-performance

I have the following table structure:

```
 users:
    id PK
    username
    email
    salt
    password
    date_created

questions:
    id PK
    user_id FK(users)
    title
    date_created
    date_updated

answers:
    id PK
    question_id FK(questions)
    user_id FK(users)
    body
    date_created
```

So I need a query that gets data from these tables and displays the user's last 5 questions and for each question the first 3 answers. Something like this:

```
"What is my favorite color? posted by user

red - posted by user1
green - posted by user2
yellow - posted by user3

.....
"
```

So this is the display I am aiming for. How can I do this in 1 query? Should I use group concat to group the multiple answers for 1 question? Or should I get the results and parse the array in PHP to group the answers by question_id. Also I need this query to be very fast. I am not sure if it will be faster making 1 query or making multiple queries that get the user questions and after that the question answers.

Comment: Posted with `homework` tag. Brave - and applaudable!

Comment: Use select - order by - limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486777/sqlite-columns-most-common-item-in-column/11486823#11486823 for ideas

Comment: same sample data (sqlfiddle preferred)

Answer (score 0):

I think the key "hint" I would give is that you can use regular CONCAT() *inside* of GROUP_CONCAT(); and then use JOINs and perhaps some of the techniques mentioned in the comments to get you the intermediate result-set that those two functions need to get you your output.